# How to remove case-insensitive duplicates from a list, while maintaining the original list order?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of strings such as:

```
myList = ["paper", "Plastic", "aluminum", "PAPer", "tin", "glass", "tin", "PAPER", "Polypropylene Plastic"]
```

I want this outcome (and this is the only acceptable outcome):

```
myList = ["paper", "Plastic", "aluminum", "tin", "glass", "Polypropylene Plastic"]
```

Note that if an item (`"Polypropylene Plastic"`) happens to contain another item (`"Plastic"`), I would still like to retain both items. So, the cases can be different, but the item must be a letter-for-letter match, for it to be removed.

The original list order must be retained. All duplicates *after the first instance* of that item should be removed. The original case of that first instance should be preserved, as well as the original cases of all non-duplicate items.

I've searched and only found questions that address one need or the other, not both.

Comment: Do you also need to maintain the cases of the letters in the first item? If not, this boils down to [How do you remove duplicates from a list in whilst preserving order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-whilst-preserving-order) and for Python 3.7 and above you can do `list(dict.fromkeys([item.casefold() for item in myList]))` (as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39835527/2285236))

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's difficult to code that with a list comprehension (or at the expense of clarity) because of the accumulation/memory effect that you need to filter out duplicates.

It's also not possible to use a `set` comprehension because it destroys the original order.

Classic way with a loop and an auxiliary `set` where you store the lowercase version of the strings you're encountering. Store the string in the result list only if the lowercased version isn't in the set

```
myList = ["paper", "Plastic", "aluminum", "PAPer", "tin", "glass", "tin", "PAPER", "Polypropylene Plastic"]
result=[]

marker = set()

for l in myList:
    ll = l.lower()
    if ll not in marker:   # test presence
        marker.add(ll)
        result.append(l)   # preserve order

print(result)
```

result:

```
['paper', 'Plastic', 'aluminum', 'tin', 'glass', 'Polypropylene Plastic']
```

using `.casefold()` instead of `.lower()` allows to handle subtle "casing" differences in some locales (like the german double "s" in Strasse/Straße).

Edit: it *is* possible to do that with a list comprehension, but it's really hacky:

```
marker = set()
result = [not marker.add(x.casefold()) and x for x in myList if x.casefold() not in marker]
```

It's using `and` on the `None` output of `set.add` to call this function (side effect in a list comprehension, rarely a good thing...), and to return `x` no matter what. The main disavantages are:

- readability
- the fact that `casefold()` is called twice, once for testing, once for storing in the marker set

Comment: great answer as it preserves original case

Comment: I found it not difficult to do this with a list comprehension.  People tend to forget that these can contain function calls with side effects.

Comment: @Alfe People generally avoid those side effects.

Comment: @Alfe OP changed input data. My answer is still valid, as it tests exact strings, not substrings. I edited to match the new inputs. See my listcomp attempt. Don't do that at home :)

Comment: @ayhan  You should be *aware* of side effects in general.  *Avoiding* them in general deprives you of several advantages they offer.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I see (about the change in the Q) (and removed my comment about that).  Your list comprehension approach really is hacky :)  I think mine is okay though.  Sure, it uses side effects, but in an acceptable manner.

Answer (score 3):

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(myList)
df['lower']=df[0].apply(lambda x: x.lower())
df.groupby('lower',sort=0)[0].first().tolist()
```

output:

```
['paper', 'Plastic', 'aluminum', 'tin', 'glass','Polypropylene Plastic']
```

Comment: It's nice for people who do data science in Python, but for everyone else - you probably don't want to depend on a 31MB dependency set just to filter out strings.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Okay, I edited my answer as the question changed in the meantime.
Now it checks if the capitalized word is found in the original list and converts it to lowercase when not found.

```
import string

def custom_filter(my_list):
    seen = set()
    result_list = []
    for i in my_list:
        item = string.capwords(i)
        if item not in my_list:
            item = item.lower()
        if item not in seen:
            result_list.append(item)
            seen.add(item)
    return result_list


print(custom_filter(myList))
```

Outputs:

```
['paper', 'Plastic', 'aluminum', 'tin', 'glass', 'Polypropylene Plastic']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mydict = {}
myList = ["paper", "Plastic", "aluminum", "tin", "glass", "Polypropylene Plastic"]
mynewList = []
for elem in myList:
  if elem.lower() in mydict:
     continue
  else:
     mydict[elem.lower()] = elem.lower()
     mynewList.append(elem)
print(mynewList)
```

result `['paper', 'Plastic', 'aluminum', 'tin', 'glass', 'Polypropylene Plastic']`

Basically,same as the first answer by @Jean-François Fabre but using dictionary.

Comment: What is the benefit of using a `dict` instead of a `set`?  Having the key and value be identical seems pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Another way by using `collections.defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict

myList = ["paper", "Plastic", "aluminum", "PAPer", "tin", "glass", "tin", "PAPER", "Polypropylene Plastic"]
d_dict = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in enumerate(myList):
    d_dict[v.lower()].append(k)

[myList[j] for j in sorted(i[0] for i in d_dict.values())]
```

Output

```
['paper', 'Plastic', 'aluminum', 'tin', 'glass', 'Polypropylene Plastic']
```

Comment: @Crickets - updated the list comprehension to preserve the list order

Answer (score -1):

I find the answer of @Gábor Fekete quite good.  Here is a continuation of his approach:

```
myList = ["paper", "Plastic", "aluminum", "PAPer", "tin", "glass",
          "tin", "PAPER", "Polypropylene Plastic"]

def is_already_in(value, used_elements):
  low = value.lower()
  if low in used_elements:
    return True
  used_elements.add(low)
  return False

used_elements = set()
print([ e for e in myList if not is_already_in(e, used_elements) ])
```

Comment: You could also add the capitalization of the words as I did in my updated answer.

Comment: Why?  I'm implementing case insensitivity by using `lower()`.